# Second request on HttpServer returns 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: c#, .net, httpserver, in-memory, web-api-testing

I have the following setup:

1) A base class for API testing

```
public class BaseApiTest
{
    private static readonly Uri BaseUri = new Uri("http://localhost");
    private static HttpServer _server;

    internal BaseApiTest()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration
        {
            IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always
        };

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        _server = new HttpServer(config);
    }

    ~BaseApiTest()
    {
        _server.Dispose();
    }

    protected static HttpResponseMessage GetHttpResponseMessageFrom(HttpMethod method, string relativeUri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpMessageInvoker(_server))
        {
            var absoluteUri = new Uri(BaseUri, relativeUri);

            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(method, absoluteUri);

            var response = client.SendAsync(message, CancellationToken.None);

            return response.Result;
        }
    }
```

2) An extension of the class for each controller I want to test:

```
[TestClass]
public class ChemicalApiTest : BaseApiTest 
{
    private const string ControllerRoutePrefix = "/api/customers/316";

    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTest() {

        // Act
        var response =
            GetHttpResponseMessageFrom(HttpMethod.Get, ControllerRoutePrefix + "/suppliers");
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode); // this is OK

        response =
            GetHttpResponseMessageFrom(HttpMethod.Get, ControllerRoutePrefix + "/suppliers");
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode); // This fails with 503
    }
}
```

*So I guess the http server responds only to the first query. Why is that, how to fix it, and how could have I known (don't see it anywhere in the documentation)*

**EDIT**

Turns out that the problem comes from instantiating the client `HttpMessageInvoker` twice. If I refactor the `BasiApiTest` class like the code snippet below, it works fine. However, I am still interested in my questions.

```
public class BaseApiTest
{
    private static readonly Uri BaseUri = new Uri("http://localhost");
    private static HttpMessageInvoker _client;

    internal BaseApiTest()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration
        {
            IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always
        };

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        var server = new HttpServer(config);
        _client = new HttpMessageInvoker(server);
    }

    ~BaseApiTest()
    {
        _client.Dispose();
    }

    protected static HttpResponseMessage GetHttpResponseMessageFrom(HttpMethod method, string relativeUri)
    {
        var absoluteUri = new Uri(BaseUri, relativeUri);

        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(method, absoluteUri);

        var response = _client.SendAsync(message, CancellationToken.None);

        return response.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the source code for `GetHttpResponseMessageFrom` and `BaseApiTest`?

Comment: @mjwills both are in my post. The first code segment has the ``BaseApiTest`` class with its method ``GetHttpResponseMessageFrom``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the [`HttpMessageInvoker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessageinvoker(v=vs.118).aspx) class has 2 constructors:

```
HttpMessageInvoker(HttpMessageHandler);
HttpMessageInvoker(HttpMessageHandler, Boolean);
```

The first one is chained to the second one with `true` value, so in my case calling `new HttpMessageInvoker(server)` is equivalent to `new HttpMessageInvoker(server, true)` and according to specification the boolean parameter is a *value that indicates whether this instance is responsible for disposing the handler.*

What seems unnatural to me is why

1. the default behavior is to dispose the dependency provided.
2. the default behavior is NOT documented.

However, the first question is a matter of personal opinion, while the second can still be answered for completeness of this topic.